# Location of signals in Django

Tags: django, web, signals

I am confused about the use of signals.
Where should I put the signal codes so that they are orderly and appropriate?
I have a signal file for an app. Where do I call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am confused about the use of signals. Where should I put the signal codes so that they are orderly and appropriate?

Often these are stored in a file named `signals.py` in the `app` directory. But that is not required at all.

> I have a signal file for an app. Where do I call it?

You load it in the `AppConfig` which will load the module when the app is ready:

```
# my_app/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig


class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'my_app'
    verbose_name = 'My app name'

    def ready(self):
        import my_app.signals  # noqa
```

Signals are often a bad idea. Indeed, signals can be circumventing, for example with a [**`.bulk_create(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) that will not trigger signals for created objects. There are also a lot of scenarios where the data can change: creating records, updating records, removing records. It turns out that keeping the same data in sync, even on the same database, is not easy. I summarized some problems with signals in [*this article* <sup>[django-antipatterns]</sup>](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html).